# "Failed to load admin schema" when using the Bloomberg API

Tags: c#, .net, bloomberg

When trying to create a session using the Bloomberg API I get the error "Failed to load admin schema". I am using the API with .NET 4.0.

This error is not mentioned in the documentation.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `app.config` file. Removing this assembly mapping fixed the error for me:

```xml
<assemblyMapping>
  <mapping name="Bloomberglp.Blpapi.resources" mapsTo="Bloomberglp.Blpapi" />
</assemblyMapping>
```